# ArcGIS Online cannot add enterprise user with hyphen in email address

Tags: arcgis-online, enterprise

When "inviting" users to join our ArcGIS Online organisation with the option "**Add members using their enterprise ID**", it works for most of the users.  They receive and email, click on the link in the email, and the account gets created.  They can then log in using their Active Directory credentials.

However, one of the users has a hyphenated surname, and the hyphen is included in their email address.  When this user clicks on the link in their invitation email, they get the following error:

> **Notification**
>
> Error in accepting invitation for user 'fred.bloggs_smith@worplace.com._WorkPlace', Invitation Id '15a11bf4Ae7bfaaa8bc29422cb7d28de9' Cannot accept invitation.
>
> User email must match invitation email.

Note that the username (which is the concatenated email address, underscore, and organisation name) has the hyphen replaced with an underscore.

It has the correct email address, as the user received the email, and it is still listed correctly with the hyphen in the list of "Pending Members".  So it is only in this username that it has been changed to an underscore.

I understand that hyphens are not permitted in the username.  That's fine.  But are they also not permitted in the email address?  Surely it should accept any valid email address?

How can I get this user registered with their enterprise login on our ArcGIS Online organisation without creating a new email alias for the user?

(Note that I'm aware of the option to "**Add members using their enterprise ID without sending invitations**".  I do not know if this would resolve the issue or not, but I have been unable to use this option due to a separate problem which is still unanswered at:  [ArcGIS Online "Add members using their enterprise ID" - what value to use for "Enterprise ID"?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343463) )

Comment: This sounds like a bug that should be reported to Esri or your local distributor.

Comment: I agree.  I will do so, once I've sorted out the other issue I've got with Enterprise logins (linked above), which IS already logged with ESRI, as my guess is they'll tell me to try that as a work around first.  :-)

Comment: It may be faster for the person to legally change their name to remove the hyphen than to get Esri to fix the bug. ;-)

Comment: Yep.  I've already talked to them about the possibility of creating a different email alias address for them.  Only if I cannot find any other solution.